# Subsets of reals which are both $F_{\sigma\delta}$ and $G_{\delta\sigma}$

Tags: gn.general-topology, borel-sets

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb R$ such that

- $X$ is an $F_{\sigma\delta}$-set (in $\mathbb R$); and
- $X$ is a $G_{\delta\sigma}$-set.

It is not necessarily true that $X$ must be $F_\sigma$ or $G_\delta$.  A counterexample is $[\mathbb Q \cap (-\infty,0)]\cup [\mathbb P\cap (0,\infty)]$, where $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb P$ are the rationals and irrationals, respectively.

**Question.** Is there necessarily an open subset of $X$ which is  $F_\sigma$ or $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb R$?

Has there been a study of zero-dimensional spaces which are both $F_{\sigma\delta}$ and  $G_{\delta\sigma}$?

Comment: You mean, other than the empty set, of course.

Comment: Yes, in the question I want a *non-empty* open subset of $X$,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, let $X$ be the set of those irrationals in $x\in (0,1)$ with binary expansion
$$x=0.x_1x_2\dots$$
such that if we define $x^{\text{even}}, x^{\text{odd}}$ by
$$x^{\text{even}}=0.x_2x_4x_6\dots$$
$$x^{\text{odd}}=0.x_1x_3x_5\dots$$
then
exactly one of $x^{\text{even}}$, $x^{\text{odd}}$ is irrational.

Comment: Since yes-or-no questions sometimes are edited in ways that make yes-or-no answers hard to understand:  this answer means "no, there need not be a non-empty open subset of $X$ that is $F_\sigma$ or $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb R$."